# not able to load file from hdfs to hive

Tags: hive, load, hdfs

I can see the file is on HDFS.

$hadoop fs -cat /user/root/1.txt
1
2
3

but from hive,  it is not recognize the file.

hive> create table test4 (numm INT);
OK
Time taken: 0.187 seconds
hive> load data inpath '/user/root/1.txt' into table test4;
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/user/root/1.txt'': No files matching path file:/user/root/1.txt

load file from local file system looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Requesting you to please put the complete path for the file.

Eg. load data inpath 'Namenode:' in to table .

Hope this help. Please let me know if you still face any difficulties.